# How to trigger Android OS to kill my background service for testing purpose?

Tags: android, performance

We know Android OS will select some activities or services to kill if the system needs more resource. I want to run a test to see if my service will be the candidate to be killed. How can I create a situation to trigger the event?

Answer (score 0):

**method 1**

command `kill -9 pid`

This is actually a shell command. We know that the bottom layer of Android is Linux. Therefore, all Linux terminal commands can be used on Android. Paste a piece of code to show how do you incorporate it into the code.

```
private void killProcess(String pid) {
    Process sh = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(sh.getOutputStream());
        final String Command = "kill -9 " + pid + "\n";
        os.writeBytes(Command);
        os.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        sh.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The most important function of this method is to tell you how to execute Linux shell commands in an Android program.

**method 2**

Kill the background service without automatic startup:

`am (Activity Manager)` command

The `am` command is a command in the /system/bin/ directory of the Android system. You can not only start an application on the terminal, but also start a service, send broadcast, intent action, and force stop process. We're going to use a function that is to **force the application to stop**.

For the description and usage of the `am` command, see the Android official website at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am.

The following is an example of code: am force-stop <PACKAGE>

```
private void forceStopAPK(String pkgName){
    Process sh = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(sh.getOutputStream());
        final String Command = "am force-stop "+pkgName+ "\n";
        os.writeBytes(Command);
        os.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        sh.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the preceding code, we call the forceStopAPK method to pass the package name of an application. Then we can kill the corresponding Android application without starting it automatically.